# iOS Twitter Streaming API usage to get public tweets in desired location

Tags: ios, twitter

I am newbie to Twitter Streaming API!

At the moment I am trying to implement Twitter Streaming API to get public posts in desired location:

```
- (void)test
{
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/sample.json"];

        SLRequest *request  = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:url parameters:nil];


        NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:[request preparedURLRequest] delegate:self startImmediately:NO];

        [connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

        [connection start];
}
```

In the NSURLConnectionDelegate callback didReceiveData: I always get null response. Where is my problem? How to make it work?